# SyntaxError .../project/assets/images/logo.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: react-native, expo

this looks like a loader error, but shouldn't Expo/CRNA support png by default?

Here's my code:

```
<View style={ styles.logo }>
  <Image source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')} style={{ flex:1, width: 150, height: 150 }} />
</View>

logo: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',

  height: 200,
},
```

My images are cached using the example code on expo.io. This is the first asset I try. How do I fix this? I can't even find any loader configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found it. It wasn't in my code, but I deleted the Expo app, restarted Expo XDE, and the error disappeared.

Comment: Also, turns out this will happen if the asset file format isn't recognised by the build pipeline. Recently I had a case where I had a file with a .WAV extension (uppercase), and I had to rename it to .wav.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have 'Hot reloading' enabled. Whenever you are going to update an image on your project, disable hot reloading from the menu shaking your device.

Answer (score 0):

Just **restart**ing the packager would solve this.

Referance: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6691#issuecomment-203073224